# How to get resource bundle value based on values received from managed bean?

Tags: jsf, xhtml, facelets, resourcebundle

I am looking for the possibility if I can get resourcbundle values based on values received from managed bean. It may be useful in datatable, datagrid, and also with other components where values are rendered.

I tried with this code:

```
<h:outputText value="#{resourceBundle['myBean.myMsg']}" />
```

But it didnt work. My outputText was not able to fetch the value from resourcebundle. Result was like:

```
???myBean.myMsg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you getting `???myBean.myMsg` that means that it could not find *myBean.myMsg* string in your resource file...

I guess you want to use the key inside the myBean.myMsg (and not the string *myBean.myMsg*)?

In that case just remove the `''` that surrounds it

```
<h:outputText value="#{resourceBundle[myBean.myMsg]}" />
```

Otherwise it will be used as a string and not as EL expression

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. After removing ' ' it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to either **declare your bundle in `faces-config.xml`**, if you want to have access to it in *all* views, like:

```
<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>path-to-your-resource-bundle</base-name>
        <var>bundle</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

so that it is accessible in view with

```
<h:outputText value="#{bundle['myBean.myMessage']}" />
```

or **load it directly in your view** with

```
<f:loadBundle basename="path-to-your-resource-bundle" var="bundle" />
<body>
    <h:outputText value="#{bundle['myBean.myMessage']}" />
</body>
```

In any case, your resource bundle has to contain the string, which contains name and value pair for your message.

```
myBean.myMessage = This is my message
```

Also worth noting that resource bundles should be placed in `src/main/resources` folder of your project. So, `bundle.properties` in the abovementioned folder will have `base-name` of `bundle`.

Regarding the usage:

- Use string from message bundle itself: `<h:outputText value="#{bundle['myBean.myMessage']}" />`
- Use managed bean's property that evaluates to your desired string from the bundle: `<h:outputText value="#{bundle[myBean.myMessage]}" />` with

  ```
  @ManagedBean
  @...Scoped
  public class MyBean {

      private String myMeggase = "bundle.string";//getter + setter

  }
  ```
- Store value in `<ui:param>`, which might be useful in templating:

  ```
  <ui:param name="bndl" value="#{myBean.myMessage}"/>
  <h:outputText value="#{bundle[bndl]}" />
  ```

  with the same managed bean.